# Using admin API to add client role to user

Tags: keycloak, http-status-code-404, admin

I'm trying to use keycloak AdminAPI (https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) to create user and assign client roles. I'm receiving correct token, and user is created but assigning roles return 404.

I'm using Postman to connect with API:

```
/auth/realms/{realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/token
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded <-with parameters ofc
/auth/admin/realms/{realmName}/users

Content-Type application/json
Authorization Bearer {TOKEN}
Body:
```

```json
{
   "username": "name",
   "enabled": true,
   "emailVerified": false,
   "firstName": "first",
   "lastName": "last",
   "credentials": [
       {
           "type": "password",
           "value": "newPas1*",
           "temporary": false
       }
   ]
}
```

Above works for me, but the next one doesn't

```
/auth/admin/realms/{realmName}/users/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/role-mappings/clients/realm-management

Content-Type application/json
Authorization Bearer {TOKEN}
Body:
```

```json
{
   "roles": [
       {
           "id": "0830ff39-43ea-48bb-af8f-696bc420c1ce",
           "name": "create-client",
           "description": "${role_create-client}",
           "composite": false,
           "clientRole": true,
           "containerId": "344e7c81-e7a2-4a43-b013-57d7ed198eee"
       }
   ]
}
```

Where 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx' is userID returned during creation and create-client role exists

I need a way to add client role via Http request. I saw there are some keycloack implementation for java but I'm using .NET CORE so there will be the target implementation but I need to have working request first as you may guess.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to pass client UUID to the `role-mappings` REST method, not the ID that you specify when creating a client in admin UI. Use `GET /admin/realms/{realm}/clients?clientId=realm-management` REST method to find out the client UUID.

**UPDATE**

In Keycloak 6.0.1 to add a role it is required to pass role name and id.

Example:

```
POST /auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{user}/role-mappings/clients/{client}

[
  {
    "id": "0830ff39-43ea-48bb-af8f-696bc420c1ce",
    "name": "create-client"
  }
]
```

Comment: I get:      `  "id": "344e7c81-e7a2-4a43-b013-57d7ed198eee",
        "clientId": "realm-management",
        "name": "${client_realm-management}" `     So should I use "id" instead of "clientId as URL parameter? this give me 500: /auth/admin/realms/{realm name}/users/e8c113c9-08b9-4600-ac84-45b9d36083b1/role-mappings/clients/344e7c81-e7a2-4a43-b013-57d7ed198eee

Comment: Yes, you should use `id` instead of `clientId`. 500 means some error occured while executing the action. This may be incorrect JSON or non existing roles I can't say for sure. Check server logs.

Comment: Also I noticed you pass incorrect JSON object. Here you can get the right JSON structure for this particular method (you need `RoleRepresentation` schema): https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.0/rest-api/index.html#_rolerepresentation

Comment: You can also go to admin console and open network tab of browser debug panel (chrome). There you will get all requests made to API.

Comment: Endpoint take one body parameter 'roles' as RoleRepresentation array (as you mentioned) witch has all parameters optional as docs says so it seems to be ok. On the other hand I've succeded to get more info about role by `GET /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/role-mappings/clients/{client}/available` I've updated JSON above but still i'm getting 500 :(

Comment: @Orzel94 see my answer I provided an example with correct JSON structure.

Comment: With your JSON I have 204 No Content :/ Checked userid and clientid in URL and they correct. User is also in correct realm.

Comment: 200-299 codes indicate successful call. Check user roles, you will see the role you just added.

Comment: Is it possible to call this api using a `bearer only` client?

Answer (score 0):

if anybody else ends up here because they are getting a 500 from KeyCloak trying to add a user to a role using the PostMan to call the following API

{{HOST_NAME}}/auth/admin/realms/{{REALM_NAME}}/users/{{POSTMAN_USER_ID}}/role-mappings/realm

then you need

1. the auth token as a Bearer Token
2. the body needs JSON with "id" and "name"
3. the headers must have Content-Type *and* Content-Length

I was leaving off Content-Length in PostMan and that is when I got the 500.  Presumably this is at least a doc bug, but also a product bug as it should a) not require the length and b) not give a 500 when it is not sent.