# Create user keycloak through api and assigning client-role realm-managment

Tags: python, rest, curl, keycloak

Create the following using keycloak rest api.

• Create a new realm (managed)

• create a new realm "admin" ex: realm-master

• assign realm-master the role of realm-managment

Trying to write fully automated CI solution for my application that is using keycloak. Where i automatically re-create the keycloak server in k8s during the test to be 100% sure everything is always the same.

**Currently using keycloak 5.**

```py
import requests

URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/auth/"
openid_url = URL + "realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
user_url = URL + "admin/realms/master/users"


data = {
    "username": "keycloak",
    "password": "keycloak-pw",
    "grant_type": "password",
    "client_id": "admin-cli",
}

token_request = requests.post(openid_url, data=data)

token_raw = token_request.json()
AUTH_TOKEN = token_raw.get("access_token")

user_data = {
    "username": "realm-master2",
    "enabled": "true",
    "credentials": [{"type": "password", "value": "super-secret-password"}],
}

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + AUTH_TOKEN, "Content-Type": "application/json"}

user_request = requests.post(user_url, json=user_data, headers=headers)
print(f"Got status code: {user_request} with data  \n")
print(user_request.json())
```

But i can't manage to assign my new user to all the roles inside client-role  realm-management.
I have tried to read the api documentation but i can't find how to perform the command.

I the documentation i try POST /{realm}/users/{id}/role-mappings/realm
But i don't understand how to the body should look like or if it's this endpoint i should use.
Found: [Keycloak - using admin API to add client role to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254627/keycloak-using-admin-api-to-add-client-role-to-user)
But didn't manage that ether.

If any knows the exact commands to perform using the api please share.

I have put way to many hours in to this task by now and it would be great if someone have a straight forward do this. If so i can probably decode how to read the keycloak documentation for future issues as well.

Thankful for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If want automate installation and configuration of Keycloak,  You can instead use [admin-cli](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#using-the-admin-cli)

you can create realm role something like this

```
$ kcadm.sh create roles -r demorealm ...
```

Comment: Sadly i can't do that, my plan is to convert this script in to LUA and use it in HELM3, and I'm assuming that the LUA integration that will happen won't have the possibility to talk to external scripts. 
I guess it's possible but at the same time it would force me to ship the admin-cli as part of my other code and i would prefer not being forced in to that.

Comment: Not ure about LUA,  but kcadm.sh is part of keycloak and you can run them as part Dockerfile Entrypoint.

Comment: Sorry for slow reply.
Well aware that i could put this as a side-care in kubernetes and use kcadm.sh to perform these tasks. But i wan't to move this logic from a sidecar to using the new template functionality that will be available in helm3.

So i want to move the logic and perform pure API calls for creating a role or two and a client so i can pull down the client secret to my pod without ever having to store any passwords in my pod. 

All i will need is a kubernetes secret that my helm user can reach and use but if my pod get's hacked they can't own my keycloak cluster.